# Understanding the math of loops in C

Tags: c

I have these three codes, which do work, but they're not printing what I expected them to print. I don't think I properly understand the math/precedence here and was wondering if someone could help me comprehend.

CODE A

```
int a;
int b = 1;
for (a = 1; a < b + 4; b++, a = b * 2)
 printf("%i\n", a);
```

I expected it to print out 4, 5. but it's 3, 9. I understand that's correct -- but why?

CODE B.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 0;
while (a > 3)
{
 b += a;
 --a;
}
printf("%i, %i\n", a, b);
```

Admittedly I struggled figuring out the math. It prints out 3, 9 --- but I don't get why.

CODE C.

```
int a;
int b;
for (a = 7, b = 2; b < a; a++)
 b += a - 2;
printf("%d, %d\n", b, a);
```

This prints out 13, 9 but I got 11, 7.

Comment: Why not move the printf's into the end of the loop so you can see what values the variables are set to after each iteration?  That would help you understand better what is going on.

Comment: Try starting from the definition of a `for` loop: the loop of the form `for (init; condition; increment) { body; }` is equivalent to `init; while (condition) {  body; increment; }`. Rewrite your loops as `while` and see if their execution becomes more clear.

Comment: For what it's worth, if I compile and run your first example I get as output `1 4 6` (which make sense, because the update expression is evaluated *after* the loop body is executed, and before we execute the update expression, `a = 1`).

Comment: Except for the first iteration, how do you expect the first loop to print any odd numbers? `a = b * 2` always makes `a` an even number.

Comment: learn to use you debugger to step through code. All will become clear then

Answer (score 2):

Let's step through the first loop:

```
for (a = 1; a < b + 4; b++, a = b * 2)
 printf("%i\n", a);
```

1. First, we execute the initialization statement, which gives us `a=1` and `b=1` (`b` was set earlier in the code).
2. We execute the test expression (`a < b + 4`, which is `1 < 1 + 4`), which is true, so we continue
3. We execute the loop body. We haven't performed any operations on `a` yet, so `a` is still equal to `1` so our output is:

   ```
   1
   ```
4. Now execute the update expression, `b++, a = b * 2`. This
   increments `b` (giving us `b=2`), and then sets `a = b * 2`, so `a = 4`.
5. We execute the test expression, and `4 < 2 + 4`, so we continue.
6. We execute the loop body, which gives us as output:

   ```
   4
   ```
7. We execute the update expression. We increment `b`, giving us
   `b=3`, and then set `a = b * 2`, giving us `a = 6`.
8. We execute the test expression, and `6 < 3 + 4`, so we continue.
9. We execute the loop body, giving us as output:

   ```
   6
   ```
10. We execute the update expression. We increment `b`, giving us
    `b=4`, and then set `a = b * 2`, giving us `a = 8`.
11. We execute the test expression. `8 < 4 + 4` is false, so we exit
    the loop.

You can walk through a similar process for the other loops.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Code A:

```
int a;
int b = 1;
for (a = 1; a < b + 4; b++, a = b * 2)
 printf("%i\n", a);
```

1. `b` is set to `1`;
2. `a` is set to `1`;
3. `a` (`1`) is less than `b + 4` (`5`), so the loop executes the `printf()`, printing `1`;
4. `b` is incremented to `2`; `a` is set to `4` (`b * 2`);
5. `a` (`4`) is less than `b + 4` (`6`), so the loop executes the `printf()`, printing `4`;
6. `b` is incremented to `3`; `a` is set to `6` (`b * 2`);
7. `a` (`6`) is less than `b + 4` (`7`), so the loop executes the `printf()`, printing `6`;
8. `b` is incremented to `4`; `a` is set to `8` (`b * 2`);
9. `a` (`8`) is not less than `b + 4` (`8` too), so the loop terminates.

You can apply a similar technique to the other cases.

Looking at Code B:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 0;
while (a > 3)
{
 b += a;
 --a;
}
printf("%i, %i\n", a, b);
```

1. `a` is set to `5`;
2. `b` is set to `0`;
3. `a` (`5`) is greater than `3` so the loop body executes;
4. `b` (`0`) has `a` (`5`) added to it, so it becomes `5`;
5. `a` is decremented, so it becomes `4`;
6. `a` (`4`) is greater than `3` so the loop body executes;
7. `b` (`5`) has `a` (`4`) added to it, so it becomes `9`;
8. `a` is decremented, so it becomes `3`;
9. `a` (`3`) is not greater than `3` so the loop terminates;
10. The `printf()` statement prints `a` then `b`, so the result is `3, 9`.

Looking at Code C:

```
int a;
int b;
for (a = 7, b = 2; b < a; a++)
 b += a - 2;
printf("%d, %d\n", b, a);
```

1. `a` is set to `7`;
2. `b` is set to `2`;
3. `b` (`2`) is less than `a` (`7`), so the loop executes the assignment operator;
4. `a - 2` is `5` so `b` is set to `7` (`2 + 5`);
5. `a` is incremented to `8`;
6. `b` (`7`) is less than `a` (`8`), so the loop executes the assignment operator;
7. `a - 2` is `6`, so `b` is set to `13` (`7 + 6`);
8. `a` is incremented to `9`;
9. `b` (`13`) is not less than `a` (`9`), so the loop terminates;
10. The `printf()` statement prints `b` then `a`, so the result is `13, 9`.

Comment: I realize you were probably typing that while I was working on my answer; I am just astonished at the similar structure of our answers.

Comment: You both beat me to it, but mine was also going to look similar. There's only so many ways to explain this.

Comment: Yeah — there is a limit to how much variation there can be in the explanation.  Thanks, both of you.  I like the equivalence of our parting sentences, @larsks.

Answer (score 0):

What might be part of the source of confusion is that a for loop in c will execute until the first semicolon found in the source code if there is not a surrounding pair `{ ... }` to delineate several lines of code.  For code A, the stuff after the second semicolon in the for loop is executed on every iteration ***and*** the `printf` statement is executed on every iteration too. In the last code snippet, code C. The `printf` is only executed ***after*** all the iterations of the for loop have completed. The same is true of the while loop in code snippet B, the `printf` executes after the `while` terminates. The while loop use of `{...}` delimiting characters makes this more obvious to the reader while the for loops do not.

Of course you still need to work through the calculations themselves too-which are also fairly tricky.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop consists of the following structure:

```
for ( init; condition; increment ) {
   statement(s);
}
```

As for how this actually executes, it is exactly equivalent to the following:

```
init;
while(condition) {
    statement(s);
    increment;
}
```

So, if we have the following code (CODE A):

```
int a;
int b = 1;
for (a = 1; a < b + 4; b++, a = b * 2)
 printf("%i\n", a);
```

That means:

```
init: a = 1
condition: a < b + 4
increment: b++, a = b * 2
statement(s): printf("%i\n", a);
```

We can translate that into a `while` loop by substituting:

```
int a;
int b=1;

a = 1;
while(a < b + 4) {
    printf("%i\n", a);
    b++, a = b * 2;
}
```

Now, we can trace the execution step by step to see what's happening.

First loop:

```
1. b=1
2. a=1
3. a < b + 4
   1 < 1 + 4
   1 < 5
   true
4. Output: 1
5. b++
   b = b + 1
     = 1 + 1
     = 2
6. a = b*2
     = 2*2
     = 4
```

Second loop:

```
1. a < b + 4
   4 < 2 + 4
   4 < 6
   true
2. Output: 4
3. b++
   b = b + 1
     = 2 + 1
     = 3
4. a = b*2
     = 3*2
     = 6
```

Third loop:

```
1. a < b + 4
   6 < 3 + 4
   6 < 7
   true
2. Output: 6
3. b++
   b = b + 1
     = 3 + 1
     = 4
4. a = b*2
     = 4*2
     = 8
```

Fourth loop:

```
1. a < b + 4
   8 < 4 + 4
   8 < 8
   false
2. End
```